Question about a proof of a theorem
Theorem 1. Suppose that $F : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, 1\}$ is holomorphic and satisfies $F(z+1) = F(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb{H}$. Then, there exists $L \in \mathbb{C}_\infty$ such that $F(z_j) \to L$ for every sequence $(z_j)$ in $\mathbb{H}$ with $\operatorname{Im}(z_j) \to \infty$.
Let $\mathbb{D}' = \mathbb{D} \setminus \{0, 1\}$.
Theorem 2. If $f \in H(\mathbb{D}')$ and $f(\mathbb{D}') \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, 1\}$, then $f$ has a pole or a removable singularity at $0$.
I want to prove Theorem 2 using Theorem 1.

What I've tried:
Let's consider the holomorphic function $g:\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{D}'$, $g(z) = e^{2 \pi i z}$. Then, we have that $f \circ g : \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0, 1\}$ is holomorphic.
I think to start with a sequence $(z_n)$ from $\mathbb{D}'$ such that $z_n \to 0$. Then, by the fact that  $g$ is surjective, we have that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exist $w_n \in \mathbb{H}$ such that $g(w_n) = z_n$. So, we have that $g(w_n) \to 0 \iff e^{2 \pi i w_n} \to 0 \iff \operatorname{Im}(w_n) \to \infty$.
Also, we observe that $(f \circ g)(z+1) = (f \circ g)(z)$, so by Theorem 1 we have that there exists $L \in \mathbb{C}_\infty$ such that $f(z_n) = (f \circ g)(w_n) \to L$. So, this implies that $f$ has a removable singularity in $0$ if $L \in \mathbb{C}$ or a pole if $L = \infty$.
Is my proof ok? Thanks!

You probably mean $\mathbb{D}' = \mathbb{D} \setminus {0 }$

Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Yes, by $\mathbb{D}'$ I mean $\mathbb{D} \setminus {0}$. I understand that is off topic, but I need to know if my proof steps are ok. It's a small proof so I think it's not a pain to read. Sorry if I upset somebody
